# loop over mulitple rrd files in directory

Tags: python, export-to-csv, cacti

I need to iterate through all **.rrd** files inside a given directory and do fetch data inside each rrd database and do some actions and export them into single csv file in python script!

How can this be done in a efficient way? it's ok to advice me how to loop and access database data over multiple files?

Comment: You ask at least two questions here: How to loop over files (google "glob") and how to read and process `.rrd` files (google "rrd python"). Please do your research and then ask for one thing at a time.

Comment: `glob` is usually not a good way to iterate over files within python.

Comment: i m ok with the fetching data from rrd files and export into csv file. The problem is there are multiple rrd files and i want to export them all in one single csv file. so i dun know how to loop every single rrd file and access into each single rrd files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a rrdtool installation with python bindings already on your system. If not, [here](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/download.en.html) is an installation description.

Then, to loop over `.rrd` files in a given directory and performing a fetch:

```
import os
import rrdtool

target_directory = "some/directory/with/rrdfiles"
rrd_files = [os.path.join(target_directory, f) for f in os.listdir(target_directory) if f.endswith('.rrd')]
data_container = []
for rrd_file in rrd_files:
    data = rrdtool.fetch(rrd_file, 'AVERAGE'  # or whichever CF you need
        '--resolution', '200',                # for example
    )                                         # and any other settings you need
    data_container.append(data)
```

The parameter list follows [rrdfetch](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdfetch.en.html).

Once you have whatever data you need inside the `rrd_files` loop, you should accumulate it in a list of lists, with each sublist being one row of data. Writing them to a `csv` is as easy as this:

```
import csv

# read the .rrd data as above into a 'data_container' variable

with open('my_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    rrd_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for row in data_container:
        rrd_writer.writerow(row)
```

This should outline the general steps you have to follow, you will probably need to adapt them (the `rrdfetch` in particular) to your case.

Comment: OK sir. i will try to test with this, thanks for help!

Comment: When I use this same code, I am getting an error with keyword 'file'. What is the 'file' stand for?

Comment: @Shehan typo, I fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out!